# xVal vs ASP.Net MVC Validation toolkit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, xval

Does anyone have any recommendations for either of these validation ASP.Net MVC Validation frameworks?

[xVal](http://www.codeplex.com/xval)

[MVC Validator Toolkit](http://mvcvalidatortoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: FYI, there are two packages which you are naming interchangably.
Validator Toolkit: http://mvcvalidatortoolkit.codeplex.com/ and Validation Toolkit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xVal is pretty much the standard way to do client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC. Actually today Steve Sanderson just released a new version of it :)

[xVal v1.0 Now Available](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/09/17/xval-v10-now-available/)

The ASP.NET MVC v2 will have client-side validation built in, but it is currently only in Preview 1 so it will be quite some time before that project will be released. You can view more about this on Stephen Walther's blog post...

[Microsoft Ajax CDN and the jQuery Validation Library](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/09/16/microsoft-ajax-cdn-and-the-jquery-validation-library.aspx)

I would suggest to use xVal until ASP.NET MVC v2 get released.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XVal as you get client and server validation with the same framework, it integrates well with MVC code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the Data Annotation Validators with great success.  I know it's not the final solution that we'll see with MVC v2, but it's easy to implement and very flexible.

http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/08/data-annotations-validation-in-aspnet.html
http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx

The advantage to this approach is that you can do some very complex validations (albeit not client-side) through creating custom attributes.  It's also very testable.